# Why I can't execute mvn clean install?

Tags: java, generics

I installed all dependencies of my project with *mvn clean install* and *mvn clean package*. When I try execute the project I receive this error:

```
[ERROR] /home/danielamorais/Documents/api-management/src/main/java/com/daniela/entity/infra/PartnerService.java:[15,68] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class UserParameter
      location: interface com.daniela.entity.infra.PartnerService
    [ERROR] /home/danielamorais/Documents/api-management/src/main/java/com/daniela/entity/infra/PartnerService.java:[39,72] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class PresentationType
      location: interface com.daniela.entity.infra.PartnerService
    [ERROR] /home/danielamorais/Documents/api-management/src/main/java/com/daniela/entity/domain/ProvisionService.java:[378,73] incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
        equality constraints: com.daniela.system.infra.PresentationType
        lower bounds: java.lang.Object
```

PartnerService interface

```
public interface PartnerService {
    void getUserParameter(Long partnerId, String user, ResponseHandler<UserParameterResponse> handler);

    void getPresentationType(Long requestorId, ResponseHandler<PresentationTypeResponse> handler);

    public static class UserParameterResponse extends ArrayList<UserParameter> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public static class UserParameter {

            private String value;

            public String getValue() {
                return value;
            }

            public void setValue(String value) {
                this.value = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class PresentationTypeResponse extends ArrayList<PresentationType> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public static class PresentationType{
            private PresentationTypeAcronym presentationType;

            public PresentationTypeAcronym getPresentationType() {
                return presentationType;
            }

            public void setPresentationType(PresentationTypeAcronym presentationType) {
                this.presentationType = presentationType;
            }

            public com.daniela.system.infra.PresentationType toInfra(){
                com.daniela.system.infra.PresentationType infra = new com.daniela.system.infra.PresentationType();
                infra.setPresentationType(this.presentationType.name());
                return infra;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error occurs in *extends ArrayList...*

Why this happen? IntelliJ shows me that everything is right (no error)

Comment: Try `extends ArrayList<UserParameterResponse.UserParameter>`

Comment: Check your java version that is used with maven. Maybe there is an inconsistency with the one used in intelliJ